# virtual memory error while making catkin class_loader

Tags: robotic-arm, catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to install class_loader on Gumstix Overo(ARM Cortex-A8). However, I got the following error while I try to catkin_make it.

```
root@linaro-alip:~/catkin_ws/build# make [ 20%] Built target console_bridge Scanning dependencies of target class_loader [ 40%] Building CXX object class_loader/CMakeFiles/class_loader.dir/src/class_loader.cpp.o
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make[2]: *** [class_loader/CMakeFiles/class_loader.dir/src/class_loader.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [class_loader/CMakeFiles/class_loader.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can make other catkin packages such as dynamic_reconfigure, but I have no idea why I cannot make class_loader. Is it because ROS cannot find libpoco-dev which class_loader depends?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57635/virtual-memory-error-while-making-catkin-class_loader/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, the problem is fixed when I restart the Gumstix Overo.

---

Originally posted by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) with karma: 441 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1